# Lightning - aura:iteration with aura:renderIf instantiates all components in if clause?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, aura

I have an interesting observation, maybe somebody can confirm this is real behaviour and what's the reason for this?

Let's say I have list of objects that I'm iterating over with aura:iteration. Each element of array have it's own type - depending on type I would want to render different child component:

```
<aura:iteration items="{!v.attributes}" var="attr" indexVar="i">

    <!-- TEXT -->
    <aura:renderIf isTrue="{!attr.Type__c == 'Text'}">
       <c:AttrText param="{!attr}"/>
    </aura:renderIf>

    <!-- RADIO -->
    <aura:renderIf isTrue="{!attr.Type__c == 'Radio'}">
       <c:AttrRadio param="{!attr}"/>
    </aura:renderIf>

    <!-- PICKLIST -->
    <aura:renderIf isTrue="{!attr.Type__c == 'Picklist'}">
       <c:AttrPicklist param="{!attr}"/>
    </aura:renderIf>

</aura:iteration>
```

Then let's say a child component looks like this:

**AttrText.cmp**

```
<aura:component>

    <aura:attribute name="param" type="Object"/>
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.initialize}"/>

</aura:component>
```

In initialize method called on init I'm putting simple console log:

**AttrTextController.js**

```
({
    initialize : function (component, event, helper) {
        console.log('initializing text component');
    }
})
```

The thing that I do not understand is why in a console I can see as many lines of "initializing text component" as there are elements in "v.attributes" array I'm iterating over.

Can somebody help me explain it? I guess that by this I'm running into some performance problems. Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this would apply in your case, but have you tried using `aura:if` instead of `aura:renderIf`?
[according to this doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_tag_renderIf.htm) :

> Only consider using aura:renderIf if you expect to show the components for both the true and false states, and it would require a server round trip to instantiate the components that aren't initially rendered. Otherwise, use aura:if as it only creates and renders the markup in its body or the else attribute.